# Dudas para comprobar un array en JUnit

Tags: java, junit

Tengo una clase Array con dos constructores y algunos metodos como inicializar o invertir, el problema es que he intentado varias cosas pero no se como comparar el metodo con el resultado esperado.

He intentado esto:

```
    package test;

    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;

    import paquete1.Array;

    public class TestArray {
        Array array;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            int[] miArray1= new int[] {4,1};
            array=new Array(miArray1);  
        }

        @Test
        public void test() {
            int[] miArray= new int[]{1,4};

            assertArrayEquals(miArray,miArray1);

        }
```

Esta es la clase que quiero probar.

```
   package paquete1;

public class Array {
    private int longitud;
    private int[] array;

    public Array (int longitud){
        this.longitud=longitud;
        array=new int[longitud];        
    }

    public Array(int[]array){
        this.longitud=array.length;
        this.array=array;
    }

    public int getLongitud() {
        return longitud;
    }

    public void setLongitud(int longitud) {
        this.longitud = longitud;
    }

    public int[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public void setArray(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public void inicializar (){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        }
    }

    public int minimo(){
        int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i]<min)
                min=array[i];
        }
        return min;
    }

    public Array ordenar(){
        int [] arrayAux=this.getArray();
        int aux;
        for (int i=0; i<arrayAux.length-1; i++)
            for (int j=i+1; j<arrayAux.length; j++)
                if (arrayAux[i]>arrayAux[j]) // si la componente i es menor que la siguiente las intercambio 
                     {                      
                        aux=arrayAux[i]; //intercambio la componente i con la siguiente
                        arrayAux[i]=arrayAux[j]; //siempre se usa una variables auxiliar para no perder los valores durante el cambio
                        arrayAux[j]=aux;
                    }


        return (new Array(arrayAux));
    }

    public Array invertir(){ //este metodo genera un objeto Array que contiene un array invertido
        Array inverso=new Array(this.longitud);//creo un objeto de la clase Array 
        //con la misma longitud que el atributo longitud
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            inverso.array[this.longitud-1-i]=this.array[i]; //
        }
        return inverso;

    }

    public boolean buscar(int n){
        boolean enc=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (this.array[i]==n){
                enc=true;
                break;
            }           
        }
        return enc;
    }

    public boolean equals (Array otro){

        if (otro.longitud!=this.longitud)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(this.array[i]!=otro.array[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

He avanzado pero sigo sin saber si lo hago correctamente.

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import paquete1.Array;

public class TestArray {
    int[] miArray = new int[] {4,1,5,2};
    Array array; //guarda el array miarray1 en operacionesArray
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        array = new Array(miArray);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructor() {
        int[] nuevoArray= new int[]{4,1,5,2};
        assertArrayEquals(nuevoArray,miArray);  
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrdenar() {
        int[] esperado= new int[]{1,2,4,5};//resultado esperado
        array = array.ordenar();//guardo mi objeto consu atributo modificado
        int[] actual = array.getArray();//guardo en actual mi array modificado
        assertArrayEquals(esperado,actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvertido() {
        int[] esperado= new int[]{2,5,1,4};//resultado esperado
        array = array.invertir();//guardo mi objeto consu atributo modificado
        int[] actual = array.getArray();//guardo en actual mi array modificado
        assertArrayEquals(esperado,actual);
    }



    @Test
    public void testMinimo() {
        int esperado= 1;//resultado esperado
        int actual = array.minimo();//guardo en actual mi array modificado
        assertTrue(esperado==actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBuscar() {
        boolean esperado= true;//resultado esperado
        boolean actual = array.buscar(1);//guardo en actual mi array modificado
        assertTrue(esperado==actual);
    }

    //Falta pasarle un objeto del tipo operaciones array creado por mi
    public void testEquals() { 
        boolean esperado= true;//resultado esperado
        boolean actual = array.equals(array);//guardo en actual mi array modificado 
        assertTrue(esperado==actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInicializar() {
        boolean esperado= true;//resultado esperado
        boolean actual = array.buscar(1);//guardo en actual mi array modificado
        assertTrue(esperado==actual);
    }

    ///no tengo que machacar las operaciones array por que es objeto de la clase Operaciones,
    //no tengo que sobrescribirlo o bien el local  no lo guardo dentro un objeto o bien creo otra variable de operacionesarray

}
```

Comment: que metodo en particular quieres probar? porque en el `@Test` estas tratando de comparar un `int[]` local del metodo `test()` con otro `int[]` local del metodo `setup()`

Comment: Estoy intentando probar todos  losmetodos el problema es que no se muy bien la estructura ni donde se declaran las cosas.

Comment: El problema es que no tengo del todo claro como traerme un array de la clase aunque estoy probando  con getArray

Answer (score 1):

La idea detras de la realización de los tests unitarios es que cada test sea independiente y se compruebe una funcionalidad especifica de manera *unitaria*.

### 1.- Procurar la independencia de tests

Deberias asegurar que no haya forma de que un test modifique el resultado de otro, por ejemplo dado el setup siguiente:

```
int[] miArray = new int[] {4,1,5,2};
Array array; //guarda el array miarray1 en operacionesArray
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    array = new Array(miArray);
}
```

Podrias tener los siguientes test no-independientes:

```
@Test
public void testInvertido1() {
    miArray[0] = -4;
    int[] esperado= new int[]{2,5,1,4};//resultado esperado
    array = array.invertir();//guardo mi objeto consu atributo modificado
    int[] actual = array.getArray();//guardo en actual mi array modificado
    assertArrayEquals(esperado,actual);
}

@Test
public void testInvertido2() {
    miArray[0] = -4;
    int[] esperado= new int[]{2,5,1,4};//resultado esperado
    array = array.invertir();//guardo mi objeto consu atributo modificado
    int[] actual = array.getArray();//guardo en actual mi array modificado
    assertArrayEquals(esperado,actual);
}
```

Solo el primer test en ejecutarse pasará correctamente, ya que ambos tests inevitablemente modifican el estado inicial del siguiente test.

La forma de evitar que esas situaciones sean posibles es procurar que la data inicial de cada test sea fidedigna:

```
Array array; //instancia nueva y equivalente para todas las pruebas
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    array = new Array(new int[] {4,1,5,2});
}
```

### 2.- Comprobar la funcionalidad

Para comprobar la funcionalidad de un metodo, primero deberias preguntarte cual es esta:

- **¿Que deberia hacer mi metodo?**
- **¿Cual es su responsabilidad?**

Si vemos por ejemplo el siguiente metodo:

```
public Array ordenar(){
    int [] arrayAux=this.getArray();
    int aux;
    for (int i=0; i<arrayAux.length-1; i++)
        for (int j=i+1; j<arrayAux.length; j++)
            if (arrayAux[i]>arrayAux[j]) // si la componente i es menor que la siguiente las intercambio 
                 {                      
                    aux=arrayAux[i]; //intercambio la componente i con la siguiente
                    arrayAux[i]=arrayAux[j]; //siempre se usa una variables auxiliar para no perder los valores durante el cambio
                    arrayAux[j]=aux;
                }


    return (new Array(arrayAux));
}
```

Se podría inferir que la intención es retornar un nuevo Array con su contenido ordenado, dejando el Array original intacto.

Para probar ese comportamiento, entonces:

```
@Test
public void testOrdenar() {
    Array originalArray = array;
    int[] original = Arrays.copyOf(array.getArray(), array.getLongitud());

    int[] esperado= new int[]{1,2,4,5};

    Array ordenado = array.ordenar();
    int[] actual = ordenado.getArray();

    assertArrayEquals(esperado, actual);
    assertArrayEquals(original, array.getArray());
}
```

Y entonces efectivamente notaras la utilidad de realizar la prueba: *detectar errores*.